# What sort of exploratory procedures should be carried out on astronomical data?

Tags: data-analysis, python, sky-survey

Upon downloading an astronomical dataset such as [SDSS DR12](https://vizier.cds.unistra.fr/viz-bin/VizieR-3?-source=V/147&-out.max=50&-out.form=HTML%20Table&-out.add=_r&-out.add=_RAJ,_DEJ&-sort=_r&-oc.form=sexa) from VizieR, what kind of exploratory techniques should be performed? I start with the basics, like [this tutorial](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/06_calculate_statistics.html), and how much missing data there is

```
RA_ICRS         0
DE_ICRS         0
mode            0
q_mode       4679
class           0
SDSS12          0
m_SDSS12    20681
ObsDate         0
Q               0
umag            0
e_umag          0
gmag            0
e_gmag          0
rmag            0
e_rmag          0
imag            0
e_imag          0
zmag            0
e_zmag          0
spCl            0
zph             0
e_zph           0
<zph>           0
redshift        0
dtype: int64
```

then a pairplot between the magnitudes.

[image]

I can also do things like plot the sky distribution from the `RA_ICRS` and `DE_ICRS` columns, and a redshift distribution histogram.

Edit based on a comment:
My goal is to use a neural network to develop a photometric estimate of the redshift for the sources in SDSS12; that's why my first step was to plot mags vs mags as in the pairplot. I've also done each mag vs redshift.

**What other exploratory investigations are worth doing on a new dataset?**

Comment: This is an incredibly broad question. Multi filter surveys like SDSS have supported hundreds of [publications](https://www.sdss.org/science/publications/) on a huge range of topics. While exploring a rich dataset and plotting "everything vs everything" as you have done is fine and a good intro, the question as it stands is like walking into a large library and saying "what book should I read?". Can you refine the question and narrow the scope down to a more specific area you're most interested in ?